# How to use Bertweet model for topic modeling

Tags: python, pytorch, bert, topic-model, huggingface

The problem is implementation of Bertweet in a topic-modeling project with understandable output like [BERTopic](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/api/bertopic.html#bertopic._bertopic.BERTopic.fit_transform), i want to use it on a relatively large (20k tweets) unlabelled dataset to segment it into topics, number of which is either user-specified or pre-defined by the model.

I've read a [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bertweet) of Bertweet and it's too short to be cohesive for a someone like me without previous experience with neural networks and transformers.
(For safety here's the whole example code from the link above)

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

bertweet = AutoModel.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base")

# For transformers v4.x+:
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base", use_fast=False)

# For transformers v3.x:
# tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base")

# INPUT TWEET IS ALREADY NORMALIZED!
line = "SC has first two presumptive cases of coronavirus , DHEC confirms HTTPURL via @USER :cry:"

input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(line)])

with torch.no_grad():
    features = bertweet(input_ids)  # Models outputs are now tuples

# With TensorFlow 2.0+:
# from transformers import TFAutoModel
# bertweet = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base")
```

From documentation example the output is:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    features = bertweet(input_ids)
```

which is `transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions`
class, that contains attributes and information i don't understand.

And few not less important questions:

1. Is this suitable for unsupervised learning tasks like
   topic-modeling?
2. How to unpack this class to a format similar to
   **document - assigned_topic**?